# Django hook to deny user access to admin based on site

Tags: python, django, django-admin

We have a Django project with multiple sites (using a derivation of the Sites framework) where each site is a subdomain of our domain.  I need to be able to deny access to the admin site for some staff users (instance of a custom user model with a foreign key to site) based on whether the user has a foreign key to the Site or not.

The custom user model looks like basically like this:

```
class SiteTenantUser(AbstractUser):
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site, null=True)
```

Your first inclination may be to suggest that we prevent authentication with the `authenticate` method of our custom `SiteAuthBackend` authentication back end in order to only let users log into their own site. That works to prevent authentication, but the trick is that we have superusers who do have cross-site access and therefore we want to use a wilcard session cookie (.ourdomain.com) to let the superusers go from site to site without having to log in every time. By doing that, however, we will now need something besides just `authenticate` to prevent cross-site access by users without that privilege. Otherwise they can authenticate against their own site and then switch to another site's admin url and have a legit session and be in the door.

In sum, although our custom auth backend prevents non-superuser staff users (who are limited to a single site) from logging in to another site's admin, it doesn't prevent them from logging into their own admin and then switching to another site's admin. Is there a straightforward hook to prevent this, similar to how Django will reject a user without `is_staff` from any admin page regardless of whether they are authenticated?

PS We have a global `get_current_site` method that uses a cached value from middleware and works from anywhere and doesn't require a request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up creating a custom AdminSite as follows:

```
from django.contrib.admin import AdminSite

class TenantSitesAdminSite(AdminSite):
    def has_permission(self, request):
        user = request.user
        return (
            user.is_active and
            user.is_staff and
            (user.is_superuser or user.site == get_current_site()))

site = TenantSitesAdminSite()
```

For my custom `site` to take effect, I had to either switch all usages of `contrib.admin.site` to use the custom `site` instead, as well as unregistering any 3rd party or contrib admins from `contrib.admin.site` and re-registering them with the custom `site`, or (evilly) monkey-patch `contrib.admin.site` to point to the custom `site`.  Not going to confess to which i did. :)

By using a CustomAdminSite and redefining the `has_permission` logic, a staff user without privileges on a particular site gets the same experience as a non-staff user does when they try to hit the admin--which is to be taken to the admin login page. @catvaran's recommendation worked, but users would just get a 403 error page and can't even get to the admin login page without going back to the site where they're authorized and logging out, and I preferred that the experience be the same for as for non-staff users (which is that any requests for admin pages where they aren't authorized take them to the admin login page).

Answer (score 2):

You can create custom middleware to deny user access.  Add it to `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` after the `AuthenticationMiddleware`.

```
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden 

class CheckUserSiteMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        if (request.path.startswith('/admin/') and
                request.user.is_authenticated() and
                user.site != get_current_site()):
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
```